# Filter in SQL from search keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table student. If I filter a student using a keyword "ann", then 1st preference should be student name starts with "ann", then student name contains "ann" in SQL Server.

Comment: What is your question here? Your requirement(?) that you describe is vague at best. What is the problem you are trying to solve here? What research or attempts have you made to resolve it?

Comment: You may find the LIKE oeprator and the ORDER BY-clause can help you getting there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE 'ann%' OR NAME LIKE '%ann%' 
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN Name LIKE 'ann%' THEN 1 
    WHEN Name LIKE '%ann%' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
END
```

Comment: working fine.. thank you so much